# C++ implementing a regex map

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I have multiple regex expressions, each mapped to a different object. After passing in a string, I want to loop through each regex expression until one evaluates to true, then I would like to return the mapped object.

What is the best way to implement this in C++? Is there a boost object available for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach is probably best.

```
vector<pair<regex,Object>> regexes;

Object* find_it( string looking_for )
{
    auto found = find_if( regexes, [&]( const pair<regex,Object>& thing )
        {
            return get<0>(thing).match(looking_for);
        }

    if( found != regexes.end() ) return & get<1>(*found);

    return nullptr;
}
```

But, the simple approach is never a fun answer.  If you use a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) you can essentially have fast look up for regexes of the style `<prefix>.*`.  With a little imagination you might be able to muster good look up time for slightly more expressive "regexes".  I, however, doubt you could transform a trie to efficiently handle general regexes.  But it could be fun to ... trie :).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a vector (or other container) of these objects that contain the regex's, you could do this with a [`std::find_if` call](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/find_if.html).  Tricky part is writing the correct predicate functor.

Comment: If writing the predicate is tricky, why even suggest this solution?

Comment: Nope. Can I expect you or Dan to provide the tricky predicate?

Comment: @Neil, it isn't that tricky, I just didn't feel like doing the grunt work.  The answer suggests an approach, isn't that good enough?  I'll provide details after I see your implementation of boost::precog.